# CRUD update and select default value Laravel 5.5

Tags: forms, crud, laravel-5.5

I created a CRUD and i want to modify the values in the edit method.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $valuechains = Valuechain::with('langs')->where('id','=', $id)->get();
    $sectors = Sector::select('sectors.id', 'lang_sector.sectname')
        ->join('lang_sector', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_sector.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->join('valuechains', 'sectors.id', '=', 'valuechains.sector_id')
        ->where([
            ['langs.ismainlanguage', '=', 1],
            ['valuechains.id', '=', $id]
        ])->get();

    $sectorsList = Sector::select('sectors.id', 'lang_sector.sectname')
        ->join('lang_sector', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_sector.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->join('valuechains', 'sectors.id', '=', 'valuechains.sector_id')
        ->where([
            ['langs.ismainlanguage', '=', 1],
        ])->get();

    $sector_selector = array();
    foreach ($sectorsList as $list) {
        $sector_selector[$list->id] = $list->sectname;
    }

    return view('admin.pages.maps.valuechains.edit', compact('valuechains', 'sectors', 'sector_selector', 'id'));
}
```

In my view i want the user to modify the sector value :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Industrial sector</legend>
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        {{ Form::label( 'Sector name' ) }}
        {{Form::select('sector', $sector_selector, array_values($sector_selector)[0],  [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ] )}}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

My issue is the following. I would like my drop down list to select by default the sector that has been defined during the creation ...
For example i want to display ICT if the sector defined in the create method was ICT and Biotechnology if the sector biotechnology was defined in the create method...

Thanks for your help

Comment: please check my bellow answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Industrial sector</legend>
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        {{ Form::label( 'Sector name') }}
        {{ Form::select('sector', $sector_selector, $sector_selector[0], ['class' => 'form-control m-input']) }}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks,

Comment: sorry i wasn't here ... unfortunatelly it doesn't work ... i think with the base you wrote i should be able to manage ....